# DIsplaying the product of matrix operations

Tags: matrix, operators, display

I am struggling to find out the option that show the final result of a matrix operations and not the necessary steps to achieve the result.

The last line of the following picture demonstrates the problem, I just want the results

[image: problem]

The code:

```
k1 = 1600;
k2 = 600;
k3 = 3200;
m1 = 1;
m2 = 2;
(*Matriz de rigidez*)
K2 = {{+k1 + k2, -k2}, {-k2, k2 + k3}}
(*Matriz de massa*)
M2 = {{m1, 0}, {0, m2}}
w1 = 40;
w2 = 50;
xi1 = 0.1;
xi2 = 0.1;
A = Inverse[{{1/w1, w1}, {1/w2, w2}}].{{2 xi1}, {2 xi2}}
C2 = A[[1]]*M2 + A[[2]]*K2
```

Comment: post your codes instead of only a picture.

Comment: @cvgmt There it is

Comment: What is your desired outcome? Seems that you can avoid all of the errors that are thrown (& get an understandable result) by just taking again the first `Part` of each portion of `A`. That is, using `A[[1, 1]]` and `A[[2, 1]]`. This is because you are trying to multiply a matrix by a length 1 list, and to instead have it be the scalar value, you need to again take the first `Part` of the list to effectively remove the curly brackets around the scalar value.

Comment: Hi Trevillian, my desired outcome is a single matrix with single elements in each position

Comment: `A = Inverse[{{1/w1, w1}, {1/w2, w2}}].{2 xi1, 2 xi2};` That is replace `{{2 xi1}, {2 xi2}}`  by `{2 xi1, 2 xi2}`

Comment: @CATrevillian your solution worked

Comment: @cvgmt your solution is also an alternative, it worked as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

k1 = 1600;
k2 = 600;
k3 = 3200;
m1 = 1;
m2 = 2;
(*Matriz de rigidez*)
K2 = {{+k1 + k2, -k2}, {-k2, k2 + k3}};
(*Matriz de massa*)
M2 = {{m1, 0}, {0, m2}};
w1 = 40;
w2 = 50;
xi1 = 1/10;
xi2 = 1/10;
```

Modifying the definition of `A` to result in a vector

```
A = Inverse[{{1/w1, w1}, {1/w2, w2}}].{2 xi1, 2 xi2};

(C2 = A.{M2, K2}) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
C2 // N // MatrixForm
```

[image]